# using htaccess to fix url mistake

Tags: .htaccess

So launched a site and made a mistake with a link and did not structure it correctly. As quite a few of these links have been picked up in Google I need to redirect the wrong links permanently without affecting the correct links and am not sure how to do it properly.

My links should be like this: /compare/itemname.html

But with the mistake they are appearing like this in Google:
 /compare/itemname  (without the .html part)

this was only because I missed off the .html when the links are created 
dynamically and have fixed this bit now.

This is in my htaccess and works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?keyword=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /compare/%1.html? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^compare/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?keyword=$1 [NC,L]
```

So how do I change from this /compare/itemname to /compare/itemname.html 
where itemname can change - without messing up the above code in the
.htaccess

Or is it better at this stage just to do a 301 redirect and again how
would I pick out the urls itemname that is missing the .html ?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: How many links are there?

Comment: from what I can see about 50 x two sites links in Google that are incorrect. Other ones are fine - it was just an extra link that I missed changing over. They all have a different itemname

Comment: Do you happen to have a .htaccess that addes the trailing slash? you could override that in the compare directory to ammend a .html instead. Let me go find mine and post it.

Comment: no it was a hard coded link that I made a mistake with and left off the .html bit. There is no compare directory though - it is just a rewrite performed by the htaccess bit posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new redirect rule to add `.html`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?keyword=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /compare/%1.html? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^(compare/[^.]+)/?$ /$1.html [NC,L,R]

RewriteRule ^compare/([^.]+)\.html$ /index.php?keyword=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Have gone with this solution but left off the QSA as i'm not sure it was needed and works without it as far as I can see at the moment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes QSA is not must to have but I kept it there in case you want to preserve any previous query sting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .htaccess in your /compare/ dir

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://www.example.com/compare/$1\.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks but there is no compare firectory - it is just a rewrite performed by the bit of htaccess code above

Comment: Create the directory then and see if it works. Or try the other .htaccess answer